# Last three scores of the user not displaying within android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-appcompat

Despite inputting my code below the only output to the user seems to be 0 in all three cases. Unsure on why this would be the case. Such as the image below seems to output the score to the user however does not register the score. To provide context provided the entire code for my end screen screenshot below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package com.example.spaceattack;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EndActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button gameStart;
    private TextView numberScore;
    private String score;
    TextView table_score;
    int lastScore;
    int best1, best2, best3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_end);

        table_score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.table_score);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        lastScore = preferences.getInt("lastScore", 0);
        best1 = preferences.getInt("best1", 0);
        best2 = preferences.getInt("best2", 0);
        best3 = preferences.getInt("best3", 0);

        if (lastScore > best3) {
            best3 = lastScore;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("best3", best3);
            editor.apply();
        }

        if (lastScore > best2) {
            int temp = best2;
            best2 = lastScore;
            best3 = temp;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("best3", best3);
            editor.putInt("best2", best2);
            editor.apply();
        }

        if (lastScore > best1) {
            int temp = best1;
            best1 = lastScore;
            best2 = temp;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("best2", best2);
            editor.putInt("best1", best1);
            editor.apply();
        }

        table_score.setText("LAST SCORE: " + lastScore + "\n" +
                "BEST1: " + best1 + "\n" +
                "BEST2: " + best2 + "\n" +
                "BEST3: " + best3);


        score = getIntent().getExtras().get("score").toString();

        gameStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restart_btn);
        numberScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreCount);

        gameStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(EndActivity.this, WaterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        numberScore.setText("Score = " + score);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}



package com.example.spaceattack;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class WaterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;
    private Button buttonHelp;
    int score;
    Button btnLogout;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMainActivity();
            }
        });

        buttonHelp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                openHelpActivity2();
            }
        });

        btnLogout = findViewById(R.id.logout);

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intToMain = new Intent(WaterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intToMain);
            }
        });
    }


    private void openMainActivity() {

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("lastScore", score);
        editor.apply();


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void openHelpActivity2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

[[image: enter image description here[][2]]][2]

Comment: where did you persist the variable `score`

Comment: My bad added an edit to my WaterActivity where I used the variable score.